# ArrayAdapter not refreshing or updating Adapter View contents

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapterview

I have been struggling with this issue for quite a while now, so hoping somebody will be able to lend a hand.

Essentially I have an ArrayAdapter that feeds an ArrayList of `CourseCardModel` objects to a Custom Swipeable View that extends `AdapterView`.

I can instatiate the adapter and view first time round absolutely fine, with Course Cards showing up and being able to swipe, however when I attempt to change the ArrayList of `CourseCardModels` associated with the ArrayAdapter, the view does not change in accordance with the new data, it just freezes.

The reason the data attached to the adapter needs to change is due to the fact that I want the user to be able to filter the Course Cards, so for example they can view cards only from Cambridge University.

Any help with this issue would be hugely appreciated, I have scoured SO for similar issues but have yet to find a solution that worked for me.

**ArrayAdapter Code**

```
public class CustomCardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private TextView courseName, uniName, entryStandards, courseDuration, studyMode, qualification,
        studentSatisfaction, gradProspects, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6;

ArrayList<CourseCardModel> items;



View v;


LayoutInflater vi;

public CustomCardAdapter(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<CourseCardModel> courses) {
    super(context, resource, courses);

    this.items = courses;

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {

        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.course_card_inner_template, parent , false);
    }

    CourseCardModel c = (CourseCardModel) getItem(position);

    if (c != null) {

        courseName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseCardCourseName);
        uniName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseCardUniName);
        entryStandards = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseCardEntryStandards);
        courseDuration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseCardCourseDuration);
        studyMode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseCardStudyMode);
        qualification = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseCardQualification);
        studentSatisfaction = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseCardStudentSatisfaction);
        gradProspects = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.courseCardGraduateProspects);


        t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardTV1);
        t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardTV2);
        t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardTV3);
        t4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardTV4);
        t5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardTV5);
        t6 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardTV6);

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newcard);

        courseName.setText(c.getCourse().getCourseName());
        uniName.setText(c.getCourse().getUniversity());
        entryStandards.setText(c.getCourse().getEntryStandards());
        courseDuration.setText(c.getCourse().getCourseDuration());
        studyMode.setText(c.getCourse().getStudyMode());
        qualification.setText(c.getCourse().getQualification());
        gradProspects.setText(c.getCourse().getGradProspects() + " / 100");
        studentSatisfaction.setText(c.getCourse().getStudentSatisfaction() + " / 5");



    }

    if(position ==0)
    {
        //float alpha = (float) 0.8;
        //v.setAlpha(alpha);
        courseName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    else if (position == 1){

        // Prepare the View for the animation
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        float alpha = (float) 0.8;
        float alpha2 = (float) 0.3;
        courseName.setAlpha(alpha2);
        uniName.setAlpha(alpha2);
        entryStandards.setAlpha(alpha2);
        courseDuration.setAlpha(alpha2);
        studyMode.setAlpha(alpha2);
        qualification.setAlpha(alpha2);
        studentSatisfaction.setAlpha(alpha2);
        gradProspects.setAlpha(alpha2);
        t1.setAlpha(alpha2);
        t2.setAlpha(alpha2);
        t3.setAlpha(alpha2);
        t4.setAlpha(alpha2);
        t5.setAlpha(alpha2);
        t6.setAlpha(alpha2);
        v.setAlpha(alpha);


    }
    else {
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    return v ;
}

}
```

**Code that attempts to alter the data**

```
// Set up and assign card adapter
    ca = new CustomCardAdapter(CardsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, generateCourseCards());
    flingContainer.init(CardsActivity.this, ca);

// Update the data in the adapter
                        ca.clear();
                        ca.addAll(coursesToReturn);
                        ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**GenerateCourseCards() Method returns the initial list of `CourseCardModel` objects to populate the view.**

Answer (score 0):

there are situations where the update works out of the box and there are situations where it does not. for the non working cases it helped to reassign the adapter to it-s displayelement

in viewPager i used

```
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

in gridview and listview i used

```
            mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mList.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);
```

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately this did not work. When i call mAdaper.Clear() it clears all of the contents and removes the view from the screen, however never adds the new data or updates it.